# Is there a canonical way to embed Git tags in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version

I'm maintaining a Rails app, and I would like a way to see at a glance that a given HTML page was served from the current version of the app.  I'm guessing that putting some data in the HEAD of each page would work.  The cap deploy release directory name would be fine, or the tag on the head of the git branch, or . . .  How do you quickly validate that your Rails app is running at the version you expect?

Comment: Interesting. Just curious, though, is getting HTML pages not served from the current version of your app a big problem for you? If so, you may wish to dedicate your efforts toward solving that issue, which would eliminate the need for a way to check...

Comment: I've just pushed out a fix that only affects an irrevocable action that shouldn't happen until tomorrow. I'm confident in the fix, since I tested it on my staging server. But I'm looking for quick assurance that my fix actually got deployed in production. I can see that the code is there by doing a 'diff -r' on the release directories, of course, but that's maybe not as quick as I was hoping for (for the future, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue, and I added a line in the deploy script:

```
git rev-parse HEAD > HEAD
```

In your case you would have to put the output in a place which where static fiels are visible from the web.

If you want a nicer output, try

```
git describe --tags > HEAD
```